# How can I increase the performance of my SQL-function?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I wrote a simple search-function in mySQL (my first function in mySQL) which works really well for me, but the performance is horrible. I work with a very large database and it takes 5 seconds to get results. This takes too long. To compare, a search with "like%" takes under 0.1 seconds.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION search (myColumn VARCHAR (255), mySearch VARCHAR (255)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE i, j, scorePoints, columnLength INT;
    DECLARE result, aSpace VARCHAR (225);
    SET i = 1, j = 1, scorePoints = 0, columnLength = CHAR_LENGTH(myColumn);
    WHILE (j <= columnLength) DO
        SET result = STRCMP(SUBSTRING(myColumn, j, 1), SUBSTRING(mySearch, i, 1));
        IF (result = '0') THEN SET scorePoints = (scorePoints + 1); END IF;
        SET aSpace = STRCMP(SUBSTRING(myColumn, j, 1), " ");
        IF aSpace = '0'THEN SET i = 0; END IF;
        SET i = (i + 1), j = (j + 1);
    END WHILE;
    RETURN (scorePoints - columnLength);
END $$
DELIMITER ;


SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(' ', t.name, t.familyname) AS myData,
    SEARCH(CONCAT_WS(' ', t.name, t.familyname), REPLACE('ABC', ' ', '')) AS score,
    t.name,
    t.familyname
FROM
    myTable t
WHERE
    CONCAT_WS(' ', t.name, t.familyname) LIKE 'ABC%'
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

I need a total time of **<** 1 second. Can someone help me increase the perfomance of this mySQL function, please.

Thanks a lot.

Thomas.

Comment: The performance difference is likely because of a different query execution plan. Try comparing `LIKE '%mySearch%'` vs `LIKE 'mySearch%'`. The performance of the function itself is only relevant if the query plan is the same (you can see the query plan by running `EXPLAIN <your query>`).

Comment: Using this function makes it impossible to make use of an index on the column being searched. And why do you use `STRCMP()` instead of just `=` to compare strings? `LIKE 'string%'` can use an index because it's matching a prefix of the column.

Comment: This appears to be finding the number of letters of partially matches words in a string. So searching for "ON" in "O ON ONE" would find 6 (then subtract 8 from that to return -2). Not sure how effective this would be as a search. It might be far more efficient to extract all the words in the column being searched into a table containing individual words. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: A database works fast because it uses tools to speed database compatible things up, e.g. by using indexes. If you run a function on a column of every row, which runs several functions on every single character in that column, you cannot expect it to be fast, because there is nothing the database can do to speed it up. You should think about a search that fits a database. Maybe try [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)? Maybe (as Kickstart suggested) split your column into rows at the spaces, use `like` and count how many rows match?

Comment: Thank You all.

@Vatev You're right, `LIKE 'mySearch%'` works a bit better for me. 

@Barmar I will change and test it with `=`

@Kickstart I compare each character in my column with each character of my search-String and if it match score++. If my column match with a space, i reset the counter for the search-String. After that i subtract the length of the column with the score.

I try to build a kind of ranking for relevant hits, cause Fulltextsearch don´t work for me and `Like` has no ranking.

@Solarflare @Kickstart I will try it, thank you.

Comment: Problem with your current ranking is that it will miss close matches when the letters positions are changed - say when someone types an extra letter. For search for lama when the string contains llama and it will only match the first letter. I have done such matching for a site search and it is complicated!

Comment: @Kickstart Yes you're right, its a transitional solution. Do you have a tip for me as I should go further?

Comment: The way I did this is quite complicated. I have a nightly CRON that breaks down all the searchable fields into words (where the words are used affects the importance of a match), and dump stop words (ie, common useless words like AND or THE), and all words are depluralised. Searches are split up when they are done, words depluralised and the best matching words found (which takes account of spelling mistakes), using levenshtein functions where the first letter matches and the word has roughly the same number of letters. Then a full search is done to find matches with the most matching words.

Comment: Can you use this *and* `LIKE` in the same query, and get valid results? If so, the optimizer will probably automatically help you by evaluating `LIKE` first, then running the function on only the matching rows.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - for the current search I don't think that would work. This currently would find _world_ in _hello world_ , and using like to narrow that down would require a leading wildcard which would render the indexes pretty useless.

Comment: Agreed, @Kickstart, the leading wildcard defeats sargability... but combining the two might still be substantally more efficient than scanning the entire table *and* executing this function against every row... sort of along the lines of "still not ideal, but perhaps better."  Better still, maybe, full-text search plus this function if it helps granularity (I'm not quite clear on what the function really accomplishes).  The optimizer very strongly prefers fulltext over any other predicate condition.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - possibly depends on the data, but I would expect LIKE with a leading wild card to be so slow as to be of little help (although a full text search might). Note that it is currently finding partial matches to assign a score. So searching for _somelongword_ would want to match against the word _some_ (giving a score of 4) in the text field.

Comment: Please describe, in English, the intent of the function.  Add that to the question.  This may help us look for faster alternatives.